# Ошибка синтаксиса (примерное положение: "SET")? (PostgreSQL phpPgAdmin)

Tags: postgresql

Делаю запрос в  phpPgAdmin
UPDATE films SET kind = 'Dramatic' WHERE kind = 'Drama';

И он пишет  ошибка синтаксиса (примерное положение: "SET")

Странно, какую бы я таблицу бы не указал, даже которой не существует,  всё равно пишет одну и ту же ошибку.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Э, а разве можно делать from из update?

Comment: Спасибо, нашел там галочку чтобы убрать счётчик.